# Airflow 2.2.5 Authlib 1.0.0 Google Login

Tags: python, oauth, airflow, authlib

I'm experiencing problems with Google OAUTH login after updating `Airflow` to version `2.2.5` and `Authlib` required as constraint to be at version `1.0.0.`

Here my previous `webserver_config.py`

```
import os
from airflow.www.fab_security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
# from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
from airflow.configuration import conf

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# The SQLAlchemy connection string.
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer"
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE_JMESPATH = "contains(['$$CUSTOM_ADMIN_EMAIL$$'], email) && 'Admin' || contains(['$$CUSTOM_USER_EMAIL$$'], email) && 'User' || 'Viewer'"

CSRF_ENABLED = True

# The SQLAlchemy connection string.
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN')

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {'name': 'google', 'icon': 'fa-google', 'token_key': 'access_token',
     'whitelist': ['@$$CUSTOM_DOMAIN$$'],
     'remote_app': {
         'client_id': '$$CLIENT_ID$$',
         'client_secret': '$$CLIENT_SECRET$$',
         'api_base_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
         'client_kwargs': {
             'scope': 'email profile'
         },
         'request_token_url': None,
         'access_token_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
         'authorize_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'}
     },
]
```

After trying to login it appears:

[image]

With this error log:

> [2022-04-06 06:44:39,729] {views.py:671} ERROR - Error returning OAuth
> user info: missing_token:

Anyone knows if it's a bug or I'm missing updates to be done in the code after the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @lepture. We updated cosntraints for `Airflow 2.2.5` and refreshed the images with Authlib=1.0.1 now !

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, and it has been fixed just now. Please upgrade Authlib to 1.0.1.